# 'javax.annotation.processing does not exist; cannot find symbol class Generated' despite adding dependecy into build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, kotlin

I wanted to contribute to one app, but when I set my IDE up and wanted to build the project, compiler thrown an error `javax.annotation.processing does not exist; cannot find symbol class Generated`. I've searched Google for the problem, people was suggesting to add `compileOnly 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'` to the main.gradle file, but author included such line already. I have turned Annotation processing on in IDE settings already. Dev said today that he can compile project. I have no idea, what's going wrong?

Maybe it's connected to the fact, that he's using Android Studio, and I - IntelliJ IDEA? But, as said by JetBrains [here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2013/05/intellij-idea-and-android-studio-faq/), that shouldn't matter, as Idea has all of the features of Android Studio. Both IDEs are up-to-date.

Comment: Hi! That info is from 2013, that might have changed, and I suspect it has. If you haven't tried yet with Android Studio, please do that first.

Comment: Okay, I'll do it tomorrow, I just wanted not to clutter my system with the same software twice, and it seems like it's a bug or like I missed something.

Comment: @Enselic I've just built apk, so that advice works. However it's still intriguing me, why that app on Intellij didn't work. Thank you.

Comment: Well, clearly they are not exactly they same, since otherwise they would not both exist. Since they are different, they can be behave differently. Which you have found an example of. Always use Android Studio for Android development. That will be a lot easier.

Answer (score 0):

I had to face the same issue. I found the solution somewhere and it resolves the problem. Add the below line in `build.gradle` file.

```
implementation 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
compileOnly 'com.github.pengrad:jdk9-deps:1.0'
```